# spring - why define variable values of properties in application.properties

Tags: spring, application.properties

I am trying to understand something about the following application.properties syntax in spring

```
some-api:
  url: ${variable.url:http://localhost:8080}
```

I know that to get the value of the above we use (for example)

```
@Value("${some-api.url}")
private String url;
```

what's the point of declaring `${variable.url:VALUE}` when I reference it with `some-api.url` ? where do you use this ?

also can you call this value in `pom.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example properties file you are referring another property, like this is how your application.yml must be looking

```
variable:
  url: http://host

some-api:
  url: ${variable.url:http://localhost:8080}
```

and vaue after `:` is the default value when `variable.url` is not defined.

> also can you call this value in pom.xml ?

No, you need some maven plugin which can read your properties file in order to do that.